# Is it possible to set a classpath in Reactjs, if it is possible then where and how to set a classpath for the packages installed

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have installed all the necessary packages but I wanted to check whether classpath can be set or not.

I have an error in my react code defining the path module is not found and cannot be resolved. I thought of trying it with setting classpath where the packages are installed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: const onDrop = async (acceptedFiles) => {
    const file = acceptedFiles[0];
    if (file) {
      try {
        const result = await convertToHtml(file);
        setFileContent(result);
        setFilePath(file.name); 
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading file:', error);
        setFileContent('Error reading file. Please try another file.');
        setFilePath(''); }}
  };

Comment: const convertToHtml = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = async (event) => {
        const fileContent = event.target.result;
        mammoth.extractRawText({ arrayBuffer: fileContent })
          .then((result) => {resolve(result.value);})
          .catch((error) => {reject(error);});
      };reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
  };const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    onDrop, accept: '.docx', 
    multiple: false,});}

Comment: Hereby, I have attached the code for reference. I am sure whether classpath can be set for the above code.